# CodeIgniter - Controller called from multiple views, how to redirect?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller let's say Post that have a function `like()` that can be called from multiple views. For exemple I can call `post/like/4` from the timeline (eg. `post/index`) or from an user profile(eg. `user/view/3`). I am having troubles with the redirect after calling the controller has I don't know how to handle the different redirections possibilities.I tried using `current_url()` but when calling this method in the controller, the current url is `post/like/4` so it ends in an infinite redirect.

Is there any way to tell the controller which URL called it and get it in order to redirect to this specific URL?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the "REFERER":

```
$httpReferer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null;
```

Please note: this is not a fool-proof method. I would probably use a session var.

Comment: I'm not using sessions but cookies so that's why I'm having troubles with this, but it seemed to work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the referer's URL. Check this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');
if ($this->agent->is_referral()){
  redirect($this->agent->referrer());
}
```

How about this?

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Or you could pass the next url and redirect afterwards

```
<a href="/post/like/4?next=current/url">Like</a>

nextUrl = isset($_GET['next']) ? $_GET['next'] : '/default/url';
redirect(nextUrl);
```

Comment: Using redirect($this->agent->referrer()) just leads me to posts/like/ID and doesn't bring me back to where I called it (posts/index).

Comment: But using redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); seems to have worked for me ! Thank you so much !!!